# Generating an XML signature in .NET with a XPath Filter 2.0 transform

Tags: .net, xml-signature

I am trying to generate an [XML signature](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) in a .NET application. I also want to make use of a [XPath Filter 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-filter2/) transform in this signature.

The [System.Security.Cryptography.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.aspx) namespace provides classes which implement the XML signatures specification. However, it seems that .NET only supports [XPath filtering as described in the xmldsig-core spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-XPath) with the [XmlDsigXPathTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigxpathtransform.xmldsigxpathtransform.aspx#Y100) class. This is not the same as XPath Filter 2.0.

Should I study the XPath Filter 2.0 specification and attempt to implement my own [Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.transform.aspx) class? Or is there an easier way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end we used the .NET assemblies from the [IKVM.net](http://www.ikvm.net/) project, which contain an implementation of the Java class libraries.

This way we could easily use Java's [javax.xml.crypto.dsig](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/package-summary.html) classes (which include support for XPath Filter 2.0 transforms) from .NET. It seems to work well.

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same problem now. Looks like the .Net framework still does not support Filter transforms. Any alternative, apart from the IKVM.net?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Chilkatsoft library](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csXmlDSigRef.html)

I know it's quite expensive, but it does the job. I'm using it in my project.